# Psycopg2: cursor.execute is not working properly

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

So, I have the following code that inserts the data of an old database to a new one:

```
...    
cur_old.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT module FROM all_students_users_log_course266""")
module_rows = cur_old.fetchall()

for row in module_rows:
    cur_new.execute("""INSERT INTO modules(label) SELECT %s WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM modules WHERE label=%s)""", (row[0], row[0]))
...
```

The last line executes a query where labels are inserted into the new database table. I tested this query on `pgAdmin` and it works as I want.

However, when execute the script, nothing is inserted on the `modules` table. (Actually the sequences are updated, but none data is stored on the table).

Do I need to do anything else after I call the execute method from the cursor?

(Ps. The script is running till the end without any errors)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You forgot to do `connection.commit()`. Any alteration in the database has to be followed by a commit on the connection. For example, the [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) states it  clearly in the first example:

```
# Save (commit) the changes.
conn.commit()
```

And the first example in the [`psycopg2` documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) does the same:

```
# Make the changes to the database persistent
>>> conn.commit()
```

Comment: Yes!! I did a `conn_new.commit()` after the for and the table gets updated now. Thank you, @Evert

Answer (score 4):

As Evert said, the commit() was missing. An alternative to always specifying it in your code is using the autocommit feature.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit

For example like this:

```
with psycopg2.connect("...") as dbconn:
            dbconn.autocommit=True
```